# How to capture second to last match?

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I'm trying to use `RegExp` with `String.replace` to replace the second to last occurrence of a word in a space-separated string.

I don't understand why my code isn't working.  I have parentheses around the correct match, so why is it replacing the match of the entire `RegExp` instead of just what's inside the capture group?

```js
const re = /(\w+) \w+$/;
const string = 'john deer senior third';
const result = string.replace(re, match => `[${match}]`);

console.log(result); // john deer [senior third]
```

Desired result:

```js
john deer [senior] third
```

Comment: The function signature is not as you think it is. The first argument is the full match, not the first capture group. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Comment: Also, `replace` won't replace only the capture group, but the full match. You can however just capture the other half, and simply concatenate it back in: `'john deer senior third'.replace(/(\w+)( \w+)$/, (_, a, b) => \`[${a}]${b}\`)`. There may be more beautiful/elegant ways to do this.

Comment: Awesome thanks, could you please copy and paste that for best answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for the signature of a replacer function in `String.prototype.replace`. The first argument is the full match, the capture groups come afterwards.

Also, `replace` will replace the full match, not only the first capture group (there can also be more than one capture group in a regex). To mitigate this, you could use a lookahead, or concatenate the latter half back in:

```js
let a = 'john deer senior third'.replace(/\w+(?= \w+$)/, m => `[${m}]`);
let b = 'john deer senior third'.replace(/(\w+)( \w+)$/, (_, a, b) => `[${a}]${b}`);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

There may be even more elegant ways to do this aswell.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That first method (with a single argument in the arrow function) is what I was trying to achieve.